# Code loops optimization in PHP

Tags: php, optimization

Is there any way to optimize this piece of code to work faster? I'd appreciate any suggestions!

This piece of code processes the transferring of edges during graph creation.

```
foreach($times_arrival as $city_id => $time_points) {
// if city is not prohibited for transfers and there is and exists any departure times for this city
if (isset($times_departure[$city_id]) && isset($cities[$city_id]))
{
    foreach($times_arrival[$city_id] as $t1_info) 
    {
        foreach($times_departure[$city_id] as $t2_info) 
        {
            if ($t1_info[0] != $t2_info[0]) //transfers are allowed only for different passages
            {
                $t1 = $t1_info[1];
                $t2 = $t2_info[1];

                $vertex_key = new Vertex($city_id, $t1, 1);
                $vertex_key = $vertex_key->toString();

                //minimum transfer time is 10 min.
                if (date('H:i', strtotime($t2)) > date('H:i', strtotime('+ 10 minutes', strtotime($t1))))
                {
                    $this->graph[$vertex_key][] = new Edge(
                        NULL,
                        $vertex_key, 
                        new Vertex($city_id, $t2, 0),
                        (float) 0,
                        $f((strtotime($t2) - strtotime($t1)) / 60, 0, 1) //edge weight
                    );
                }
                //if transfer is on the bound of the twenty-four hours
                else if (date('H:i', strtotime('+ 24 hours', strtotime($t2))) > date('H:i', strtotime('+ 10 minutes', strtotime($t1))))
                {
                    $this->graph[$vertex_key][] = new Edge(
                        NULL, 
                        $vertex_key,
                        new Vertex($city_id, $t2, 0),
                        (float) 0,
                        $f(strtotime('+ 24 hours', strtotime($t2)) - strtotime($t1) / 60, 0, 1) //edge weight
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

example of variables:

```
var_dump($times_arrival); //$times_departure have the same structure
array
  3 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '08:12' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string '2' (length=1)
          1 => string '08:40' (length=5)
  41 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '21' (length=2)
          1 => string '12:40' (length=5)
```

Comment: Wow! `foreach(foreach(foreach($foo => $bar)))`

Comment: Post some of `$times_arrival` data, please.

Comment: How long is this part of the code taking, and for how big of an array?  Are you certain that the total time for the script is mostly taken specifically by this loop?  For instance, this takes 0.02 seconds: http://ideone.com/PPscN

Comment: first thing i see is you could just replace the one strtotime('+ 24 hours', strtotime($t2)) with strtotime($t2) + 86400

Comment: As a general recommendation, you should comment your code so that people have an easier time following what you're doing.

Comment: @mellamokb size of created graph is more than 2000 elements, size of $times_arrival is near 1000 elements. this pies of code runs a lot of times and without this piece of code it takes 0.5 sec to create graph, with it: 10-13sec.

Comment: @NathanielFord I've add some comments to code

Comment: @Yekver One more clarification: you have three inputs, correct? $times_arrival, $times_departure and $cities, right? Can you comment your sample input so that we know what each integer should correspond to (either a city index or transit time, I'm guessing?)

Comment: @Yekver The more I look at this, the less I'm understanding the incoming data structure. In the provided array, is it (index of city){ arrival(from what city, when), arrival(from what city, when) }, or something else? How do you know when a train arriving left from another city? Otherwise, aren't you saying that for each arrival time, you have an edge for each departure time in the ten minute to 24 hour window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all!
The reason of slow speed was coz of using functions `strtotime()` and `date()`.

Answer (score -1):

In that case only you can say whether you chose a good or bad algorithm. In my point of view your code not has no extra computations.

Only one recommendation - use Xdebug to profile your code and find out where the bottleneck is, if possible.

Comment: At the very least he is likely to be able to do preprocessing on his nodes, which will lower his expected big-O from ~O(n^3) to O(n^2), or perhaps O(nlogn), depending on what exactly he has to do.

Comment: Now it O(n^2) not n^3 and possible decrease it to O(nlogn) or not how i and you say "depending on what exactly he has to do". But it not clean mathematics - its program and possible may be ultimately speed up by optimize code but not algorithm.

Comment: It's technically O(m*n^2), where n is the length of the arrival array and m is the length of the departure array. We know this because there are three nested for-loops. I guarantee there is a faster way algorithmically to do this, if he can post clarification about his data input.